# After saving an xlsm as xlsx, why does opening the new file close the old one?

Tags: excel, vba

**The Background:**
I am trying and failing to save and modify a file that has code in a "no code" format. I have been experimenting, and I can open a file that already exists from within an .xlsm and it works as expected. The script continues to run and I can modify and close the second file from within the script of the first file:

```
Sub testExistingWorkbook()

    Dim wbkName As String
        wbkName = "WorkWithWorkbookTest.xlsx"

    Workbooks.Open (wbkName)
    '~~>...code to modify goes here
    Workbooks(wbkName).Close

End Sub
```

However, if I save a copy of the first file without macros, and then open and modify that macro-free file afterward, the file with code closes when the file without code opens.  Although the code looks like it is trying to do the same thing, it does *not* work as in the first example.

I have tried many different configurations but in every case the script stops running the second I open the next file. The example code below, for example, stops after 'Workbooks.Open (wbkName)'. At that moment it simultaneously closes the .xlsm, an action that my code does not seem to request (but I think must be implicit in the code). Initially I had coded it to create an object as it opened: 'Set wbk2 = Workbooks.Open(wbkName)' but I found this did not work in either scenario. Then I thought maybe it was a function of 'Workbooks' being a collection of all *open* workbooks, so if I opened a file that was not already opened, it would essentially knock another workbook out of the collection (silly, I know). But that possibility is eliminated by the example code above.  For a time I thought maybe it was because the name was the same and somehow not differentiating between the .xlsx and .xlsm, but the below code uses a different name and results in the same problem, so that that is not a factor.

```
Sub testSaveAsWorkbook()

    Dim wbkName As String
        wbkName = "SuperSecretWorbookTest.xlsx"

    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=wbkName, FileFormat:=61
    Workbooks.Open (wbkName)
    '~~>Code would go here, but the original file has closed and only
    '   the new SuperSecretWorkbookTest.xlsx is open
    Workbooks(wbkName).Close

End Sub
```

**The Question:**
In thinking about and writing this question, I realized that the problem really starts at the moment I execute 'ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=wbkName, FileFormat:=61' because that is when the first workbook is closed, and the new workbook takes its place. The IDE just doesn't know it yet, so even stepping through the code it only realizes the .xlsm file is no longer active when it tries executing the next line of code.

So my question is why does 'Workbooks.SaveAs' close the first file like this? And more importantly, what can I do to keep my file open and finish the script?

Comment: what is the name/where is the `sub testSaveAsWorkbook()` stored?

Comment: Remove the extension  xlsx from the file name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were to do this manually by going to *File* > *SaveAs*  to save an *xlsm* as an *xlsx*, and clicking "Yes" to continue saving as a macro-free workbook, you'd see that the *xlsm* is "no longer open" — only the new *xlsx* is. Which is as it should be, you've saved it as such. The `Workbooks.Open` call doesn't close the original *xlsm*; it's already gone.

In other words, in response to your observation:

> In thinking about and writing this question, I realized that the problem really starts at the moment I execute `ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=wbkName, FileFormat:=61` because that is when the first workbook is closed, and the new workbook takes its place.

That is exactly what `SaveAs` does.

[`Workbook.SaveCopyAs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.savecopyas) "doesn't modify the open workbook in memory." Perhaps you can first save a copy, open the copy and then save as *xlsx* in the end and delete the *xlsm* copy.

```
Sub testSaveAsWorkbook1()

    Dim wbkName As String, wbkExtension As String
    wbkName = "SuperSecretWorbookTest"
    wbkExtension = ".xlsm"

    ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=wbkName & wbkExtension

    Dim copyWbk As Workbook
    Set copyWbk = Workbooks.Open(wbkName)

    ' Do whatever you want with the copy

    copyWbk.SaveAs Filename:=wbkName, FileFormat:=61
    Kill copyWbk.Path & "\" & wbkName & wbkExtension
    copyWbk.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Funny, I almost got there while writing the question, and afterward my wife observed exactly what you did: "if you select File>SaveAs, doesn't it behave exactly like you describe?"  Thanks for getting me the rest of the way there.

Comment: Ha... glad to help :) This was an enjoyable question to answer. I was initially confused why, in your words, "the IDE just doesn't know it yet, so even stepping through the code it only realizes the .xlsm file is no longer active when it tries executing the next line of code." After the `SaveAs`, it appeared that the new `xlsx` file still had the code module within the VBE... anyway, glad to help. I learned something with the question so happy you asked it.