# Unprotect worksheet when doing a Save As?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro-enabled workbook that is used to compile a report. This workbook has some protected ranges due to a series of formulas that I don't want someone accidentally modifying.

I don't want to send the macro-enabled workbook as it's customer-facing, and would prefer to send a standard XLSX file. Additionally, others will be using this same macro-enabled workbook to generate similar reports.

I have a macro written that makes some data modifications to the workbook, followed by triggering a Save As prompt (code for save-as below).

I know it's possible to unprotect a workbook using VBA...but is it possible to unprotect the ranges in the *saved* XLXS copy through VBA in my macro-enabled workbook?

The code examples I have found unprotect the range in the existing workbook (i.e. the macro-enabled workbook).

Thanks!

```
FileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("Report", _
    "Excel Workbook, *.xlsx", 1, "Select your folder and filename")

If TypeName(FileName) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLStrictWorkbook
```

Comment: One option is to open the newly saved workbook and unprotect the ranges in it (easily done with VBA). Or you can unprotect the ranges in the macro-enabled workbook but then never save (i.e. only save as .xlsx, never overwriting the .xlsm).

Comment: @BigBen *"One option is to open the newly saved workbook and unprotect the ranges"* Actually thats not correct. Because if you are in your `original.xlsm` and there use `.SaveAs` to save your workbook as `B.xlsm` you are immediately working with B not with the original. Also see my answer below.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ - oh yeah, duh... of course I've already answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54642447/after-saving-an-xlsm-as-xlsx-why-does-opening-the-new-file-close-the-old-one) that covers that :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that whenever you make changes to a workbook A and then use `.SaveAs` and save as workbook B. All those changes are only saved in B (but not in A)! If you want to have them in both you first need to `.Save` A and then `.SaveAs` as B.

This also means you can `.Save` A, then make the changes to unprotect cells etc and then `.SaveAs` B and only the cells in B are unprotected.

Also note that after using `.SaveAs` B you are actually working with B not with A. So all changes made after  `.SaveAs` B are applied to B and A is actually closed.